# How can I use node_load and render contextual links

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have an array of node IDs with which loop through and run `node_load($nid)` to retrieve the data for each of those nodes. Take for example the below code- that's roughly how it works at the moment.

```
foreach( $node->field_flights['und'] as $flight ):
    $flightNode = node_load($flight['nid']);

    echo $flightNode->title;
```

What I want to achieve is to load the node, then be able to do something along the lines of `echo render($flightNode);` so that it loads the template file for that node and I can render the `$title_suffix` variable in the node template which has been loaded.

I've tried the following to no avail. Nothing is output at all.

```
$flightNode = node_load($flight['nid']);
$builtFlightNode = node_build_content( $flightNode );
echo render( $builtFlightNode );
```

Would anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view/7) to prepare the render array. For performance it might be wise to consider using [`node_load_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) (and it's counterpart [`node_view_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view_multiple/7)) like this:

```
$nids = array();
foreach($node->field_flights['und'] as $flight):
  $nids[] = $flight['nid'];
endforeach;

$flight_nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

$view_mode = 'teaser'; // could also be 'full'
$views = node_view_multiple($flight_nodes, $view_mode);

// Renders all nodes in one go
echo render($views);
```

If that doesn't fit in with what you're doing though this should work on a node by node basis:

```
foreach($node->field_flights['und'] as $flight):
  $flight_node = node_load($flight['nid']);
  $view = node_view($flight_node, $view_mode);
  echo render($view);
endforeach;
```

If you need to modify the content before it's rendered, you can just step through the `$views` or `$view` arrays and change what you need to before running it through `render()`. If you just want a particular part of the node content rendered, again just step through the array and apply `render` to the particular sub-array you're interested in.

Comment: The first option is actually the best thing since sliced bread. Except for the small error btw, `$nodes` should be `$flight_nodes`. Learned something new and massively useful. Thanks

Comment: I really appreciated this code also. I have node types sermon and sermon_series. I wanted to use the series image on each sermon page. This helped me accomplish it. I added the assumption that you can use render on the newly loaded node in the same way as the $content and was able to render just a field from the node.

`print render($sermon_series['field_sermon_series_image']);`